# Display a randomly selected .TXT file content in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch-file which would select a random .txt file (from over 1500 files) from within 1 folder and display it's content in CMD in Windows.

Got to this but unable to display text in the `cmd` as the file opens in text editor. The last line should be `More` not `Call Start`.

```
Set "SrcDir=\RECON\txt"
Set "ExtLst=*.txt"
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%SrcDir%" %ExtLst%') Do (Set /A i+=1
Call Set "$[%%i%%]=%%A")
Set /A #=(%Random%%%i)+1
Call Start "" "%%$[%#%]%%"
```

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Just make life easier for yourself and use `delayedexpansion` it makes things more readable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "SrcDir=\RECON\txt"
Set "ExtLst=*.txt"
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%SrcDir%" *%ExtLst%') Do (
   Set /A i+=1
)
Set /A rnd=!Random!%%%i%
type "!$[%rnd%]!"
```

Note also that with the fact you are using `where` you need to ensure that your `SrcDir` variable never contains a trailing `\` or you will get an error, because of using double quotes in the `for` loop.

Obviously, you can replace `type` with `more` if it suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

okay so this is a realy bad script that I made that uses text files to store info and powershell combinations. so pretty much it's bad and you shouldn't ever do anything like I just did. but it does get the job done.

```
@echo off
set loc2=%CD%

:: replace the line below with "set location=[folder with the files]" if you want to use the same folder every time

set /p location=folder:
cd %location%
dir /b>"%loc2%\dir.txt"
cd %loc2%
find /c "." "dir.txt">"find.txt"
powershell -Command "(gc '%loc2%\find.txt') -replace '---------- DIR.TXT: ', '' | Out-File -encoding ASCII 'replace.txt'"
cd %location%
PowerShell "GC '%loc2%\replace.txt' -TotalCount '2'|Select -L 1">"%loc2%\temp_txt2.txt"
< "%loc2%\temp_txt2.txt" (
  set /p file_count=
)
del "%loc2%\replace.txt"&del "%loc2%\find.txt"
SET /A ran=%RANDOM% * %file_count% / 32768 + 1
PowerShell "GC '%loc2%\dir.txt' -TotalCount '%ran%'|Select -L 1">"%loc2%\temp_txt.txt"
< "%loc2%\temp_txt.txt" (
  set /p file_name=
)
type "%file_name%"
del "%loc2%\temp_txt.txt"&del "%loc2%\dir.txt"&del "%loc2%\temp_txt2.txt

:: put whatever other scripts you want after this
pause
```